# Koin injection from constructor in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I can't call inject from constructor for my project via Koin DI.

If I use "**... by inject()**" for injection the DataRepository class, all works perfectly. But I want to provide inject in a constructor of a class.

I have a **crash** in the CounterPresenter class in "**repo.addPayment(payment)**" line. 
Look down the page.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
 Caused by: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No compatible definition found. Check your module definition
```

Here is my structure:

[image]

**Koin DI**
Please, how I can change this module for successful working?

```
val repositoryModule = module {
    single { PrefsManager() }
    single<IRepository> { DataRepository(get() as LocalRepository) }
    single<ILocalRepository> { LocalRepository(get()) }
}

val databaseModule = module {
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(androidApplication(), AppDatabase::class.java, Enviroment.DATABASE_NAME).build()
    }
    single { get<AppDatabase>().getCounterDao() }
}

val presentersModule = module {
    factory { CounterPresenter() }
    factory { SplashPresenter() }
}
```

**class DataRepository**

```
class DataRepository(private val localRepository: ILocalRepository) : IRepository {

    init {  Log.d("ROMAN", "init DataRepository") }

    override suspend fun addPayment(payment: Int) {
        localRepository.addPayment(payment)
    }
}
```

**class LocalRepository**

```
class LocalRepository(private val counterDao: CounterDao) : ILocalRepository {

    override suspend fun addPayment(payment: Int) = runBlocking {
        counterDao.insertPayment(Payment(payment))
    }
}
```

**class CounterPresenter**

```
class CounterPresenter : BasePresenter<CounterContract.View>(), CounterContract.Presenter {
    private val repo: DataRepository by inject()


    override fun onViewCreated() {
        super.onViewCreated()
        launchIO { repo.addPayment(payment) }
    }
```

Comment: pls provide detailed stacktrace: Koin typically shows much more than just "no compatible definition found"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To inject dependencies to any class, the class must implement `KoinComponent` interface.(except Activity and Fragments)

Do this and your code should be working:

```
class CounterPresenter : BasePresenter<CounterContract.View>(), CounterContract.Presenter, KoinComponent {
    private val repo: DataRepository by inject()


    override fun onViewCreated() {
        super.onViewCreated()
        launchIO { repo.addPayment(payment) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. I was trying to inject an instance of dao into a repository class. Just added KoinComponent and changed the import, it worked.